# networked aframe not working correctly with A-frame version 1.2

Tags: aframe, aframe-networked

### Problem

Hi, I am creating a networked A-frame scene using a starting project. The project however, using an obsolete version of A-frame that isn't comp addable with vr headsets. Whenever I try to change the script sheet to the current version of A-frame, the networked aspect of the scene stops working. I can open up two tabs however when I move the avatar on one of the tabs, it doesn't update on the other. I'm wondering how I can get the current version of A-frame in my networked scene but have the networked aspects still be functional. This means when I open two tabs and move my avatar on one tab, it should move on the other tab as well. How can this be done?

### Links

Link to the glitch project: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/remix/naf-dynamic-room

Link to the networked A-frame component: https://www.npmjs.com/package/networked-aframe

Current version of A-frame I would like add instead of outdated version:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the main thing you want to check is the Network A-frame version. If you use
A-frame version 1.3.0(the latest stable release). Then your network A-frame version should also be updated to 0.9.0 .Similar to  A-frame NAF team updates it frequently for various capabilities

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/networked-aframe@^0.9.0/dist/networked-aframe.min.js"></script>
```

the same follows for 1.2.0
you can get reference from the starter code here [Network Aframe](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/thoughtful-economic-waitress)